# Calling ffmpeg in a for loop in a Python 3 script

Tags: python-3.x

I try to use ffmpeg in a Python 3 script in a for loop to convert each .m4v file to a .wav file (keeping the same name) then delete the .m4v file. I am able to do it inside a source directory with the following code, it works.

```
import os
dst="Path\\sourcefolder"
os.chdir(dst)
os.system("ffmpeg -i test.m4v test.wav")
os.remove("test.m4v")
```

However, I want to be able to do it for all m4v files with different paths in the source, a recursive directory. I expect something like the following;

```
for i in range(0,len(m4v_Paths))         
    infile=m4v_Paths[i]  # example i th file "Path\\source\\folder\\movie.m4v"
    outfile=os.path.join(os.path.splitext(m4v_Path[i])[0]+'.wav')  # remove '.m4v' extension add ' .wav'
    os.system("ffmpeg -i infile outfile")
    os.remove(infile)
```

I have read the similar titled questions, but they didn`t help. I tried to pass each path to command line as an argument, but nothing happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to perform your task using `os` module:

For example i have these directory's files:

```
.
├── ffmpeg_script.py
├── file1.txt
├── file2.txt
└── file.txt

0 directories, 4 files
```

And i'll create new files with the same name but with a new extension. So here is `ffmpeg_script.py` code:

```
import os

current_file_name, _ = os.path.splitext(__file__)
# Or add your custom path
current_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

# Get a list of all the filenames in the current path
list_paths = []
for _, _, filenames in os.walk(current_path):
    list_paths = filenames


for path in list_paths:
    # Get file name from the path
    file_name, _ = os.path.splitext(path)
    # Don't rename the current python file
    # because the python file is under the same directory
    # The if clause in meant valid only if the python script
    # is under the same directory of your files's list that you need to modify
    if file_name != current_file_name:
        # add new extension to the file
        new_file_name = file_name + '.wav'
        # Build the path of the new wav file
        new_file_name_path = os.path.join(current_path, new_file_name)
        # create the new file under the new path
        # Or update with the system command you want to do
        os.system('touch {new_file_name}'.format(
            new_file_name=new_file_name_path
        ))
        # Remove the old file
        os.remove(path)
```

So, the directory's new tree will be:

```
.
├── ffmpeg_script.py
├── file1.wav
├── file2.wav
└── file.wav

0 directories, 4 files
```

The main idea here, is to split the filename and it's extension and rebuild it again when you pass it to your command as an argument within the `os.system()` function.

Comment: Hi Chibeb, thank you very much for detailed explanation. Hope my next question won't be too meaningless.  I see that this code change the extension to wav and doesnt use ffmpeg command. I was wondering if the wav files created by changing the extension would be the same as wav files created by using ffmpeg command line for convertion? Or am i miss something?

Comment: @kutlus Of course, just use your own command using `os.system` and use `ffmpeg` there. I've used `touch` command and you can use yours. Also, don't forget to accept the answer that fills your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem a long time ago execing it from a different language so this may not be your answer. I seem to remember ffmpeg wanted all the files in the same directory. The way I solved it was by creating soft links to the original files within a temporary directory. Then when I was all done it removed the tmp directory with the soft links.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found a way to do it. It is slower than I like it to be but it does exactly what I wanted. I am sure there are more efficient codes for this task but putting mine here just in case anyone has a similar issue.

```
import os

#first create a path list for all the files in the recursive source
src='Path\\sourcefolder'
fpathlist=[]
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(src):
     for fpath in files:
         fpathlist.append(os.path.join(path, fpath))       
length=len(fpathlist)


mycwd = os.getcwd()
for fpath in range(0,length):
    if (fpath.endswith(".m4v")):
        filename=os.path.basename(fpath)
        dst=os.path.dirname(fpath)
        mycwd = os.getcwd()
        os.chdir(dst)
        os.system("ffmpeg -i {0} temp_name.wav".format(filename))
        org_name=os.path.join(dst, filename)
        no_ext=os.path.splitext(org_name)[0]
        temp_name=os.path.join(dst, "temp_name.wav")
        new_name = os.path.join(no_ext+'.wav')
        os.rename(temp_name,new_name)
        os.remove(org_name)
        os.chdir(mycwd)
```